# How to check paramaters stored as cookie in if-else condition?

Tags: javascript, cookies, url-parameters

I want to check `cookie` values stored as parameters in `if-else` condition. I added a variable `params` to be able to pass it into a new url for those cookies using the `XMLHttpRequest()` later. But it seems that the problem in my if-else condition is that it only pulls the first parameter entered by the user.

Example:

1.) When user adds a parameter for the first time like `?gclid=sample` in the url. It will alert that parameter.

2.) But when user enters another url parameter the second time like `?cjevent=3212` it will still return the first parameter entered by the user.

**Javascript**

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
try {
    var url_string = (window.location.href).toLowerCase();
    var url = new URL(url_string);

    // check parameters if exists
    ['gclid', 'token', 'fbclid', 'cjevent'].forEach(function (key) {
        var value = url.searchParams.get(key);
        if (value) {
            //token expires in 6 hours
            document.cookie = `${key}=${value}; max-age=21600` + ';path=/';
        }
    });

    const getCookieValue = (name) => (
        document.cookie.match('(^|;)\\s*' + name + '\\s*=\\s*([^;]+)')?.pop() || ''
    )
    var params = '';

    // pass parameters if gclid, token, fbclid, cjevent
    if(getCookieValue('gclid')) { params = 'gclid=' + getCookieValue('gclid');}
    else if (getCookieValue('token')) { params = 'token=' + getCookieValue('token');}
    else if (getCookieValue('fbclid')) { params = 'fbclid=' + getCookieValue('fbclid');}
    else if (getCookieValue('cjevent')) { params = 'cjevent=' + getCookieValue('cjevent');}

    alert(params);

    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Issues with Parsing URL Parameter's - " + err);
    }

}
</script>
```

I believe I need to refactor my condition in here.

```
if(getCookieValue('gclid')) { params = 'gclid=' + getCookieValue('gclid');}
    else if (getCookieValue('token')) { params = 'token=' + getCookieValue('token');}
    else if (getCookieValue('fbclid')) { params = 'fbclid=' + getCookieValue('fbclid');}
    else if (getCookieValue('cjevent')) { params = 'cjevent=' + getCookieValue('cjevent');}
```

Is there anyway to get the latest parameter entered by the user and check it using `alert()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have no need this conditions. As I understand you, all cookies can be available at the same time and you need their latest actual values. So, we can modify you code this way:

```
window.onload = function() {
  try {
    const url_string = (window.location.href).toLowerCase();
    const url = new URL(url_string);
    const paramsArray = ['gclid', 'token', 'fbclid', 'cjevent'];
    const getCookieValue = (name) =>
      document.cookie.match('(^|;)\\s*' + name + '\\s*=\\s*([^;]+)')?.pop() || '';

    // One loop for both: write and read cookies.
    paramsArray.forEach(function (key) {
      const value = url.searchParams.get(key);

      if (value) {
        const currentCookieValue = getCookieValue(key);
        const cookieDoesNotExist = !currentCookieValue;
        const valuesAreNotEqual = currentCookieValue !== value;

        //token expires in 6 hours
        document.cookie = `${key}=${value}; max-age=21600;path=/`;

        if (cookieDoesNotExist || valuesAreNotEqual) {
          const params = `${key} = ${getCookieValue(key)}`;
          alert(params);
        }
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Issues with Parsing URL Parameter's - ${err}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. but I've tried testing this one, it seems that it will alert all parameters input by the user.

Comment: Yes, just one. Do you need a last one?

Comment: What I mean is that all parameters are alerted everytime a user enters another parameter. Example user enters `?gclid=111` then enter another `?token=321` and so on. It will alert those values in the `cons params`